# Multiply List of RGB values Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, rgb, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply a list of RGB Values, more specifically multiply each element with a different variable
e.g.

```
colors = [(70, 76, 75), (97, 107, 93)]
multipliers = [2,3]
prod = lambda a,b: [a[i]*b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
newcolors = (prod (colors, multipliers))
```

Desired Output:

```
[(70,76,75), (70,76,75), (97, 107, 93), (97, 107, 93), (97, 107, 93)]
```

But the output I'm getting is

```
[(70,76,75, 70,76,75), (97, 107, 93, 97, 107, 93,97, 107, 93)]
```

The returned List does not consist of RGB Values anymore

What seems to be working is

```
n = 2
newcolors = sorted(colors*n)
```

Output:

```
[(70,76,75), (70,76,75), (97, 107, 93), (97, 107, 93)]
```

But that way all RGB values are multiplied by the same `n`-amount of times.

Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Answer (score 3):

you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions) and the built-in function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#zip), pair with `zip` each element from `colors` with each number from `multipliers` in one for loop, then in a second for loop you are saying how many times the current color should be repeated

```
[e for e, m in zip(colors, multipliers) for _ in range(m)]
```

output:

```
[(70, 76, 75), (70, 76, 75), (97, 107, 93), (97, 107, 93), (97, 107, 93)]
```

you can also use 2 for loops, with one loop you iterate over each pair (color, multiplier) and in the second/inner loop you are repeating the current color with the current multiplier and [extending](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/datastructures.html) the `result` list:

```
result = []
for e, m in zip(colors, multipliers):
    result.extend([e] * m)
print(result)
```

output:

```
[(70, 76, 75), (70, 76, 75), (97, 107, 93), (97, 107, 93), (97, 107, 93)]
```

Comment: an explanation would make this a great answer

Comment: @Tryph I hope is better

Comment: much better IMO ;) I was writing an answer to talk about the second solution but since you did it, I allowed myself to add links to the Python doc to your answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools

colors = [(70, 76, 75), (97, 107, 93)]
multipliers = [2,3]

print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(itertools.repeat, colors, multipliers))))
```

Output:

```
[(70, 76, 75), (70, 76, 75), (97, 107, 93), (97, 107, 93), (97, 107, 93)]
```

**Explanation:**

Here, `map` function will apply the values from `colors` and `multipliers` to repeat one by one. So, the result of map will be

```
list(map(repeat, x, y))
[repeat((70, 76, 75), 2), repeat((97, 107, 93), 3)]
```

Now, we use `chain.from_iterable` to consume values from each and every iterable from the iterable returned by map.